# Setting up machine learning workstation as server for multiple users

Tags: linux, ssh, python, remote-access

Company purchased machine learning workstation and put me in charge of running and maintaining it.

Goal: Develop our own ML applications, and also allow our global offices to connect to the workstation to train/run their own models. I would also setup standard training frameworks for other global teams to get started training classification and object detection models.

Development language: Python

Workstation Specs:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- GPU drivers and common ML libaries all came pre-installed
- Intel Core i9-9920X, 4x RTX 2080 Ti
- 128 GB RAM, 2 TB NVMe + 2 TB SATA SSD

Current plan is to setup different user accounts for all users and they would ssh into their own accounts. However, I'm not confident that this is going to work. What happens when users want different library versions etc.?

Are docker containers the way to go? This way everyone can have their own isolated environment that they're free to setup as they like. I recently learnt about python virtual environments too, and this sounds like the simplest solution now.

I don't have much experience in this area, and I'm just getting started. Please share you experience/suggestions, and let me know if you need additional details, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Python virtual environments are meant  exactly for your use cases. In that way you will have python packages dependencies for every project so you will avoid global installations and version mismatches.

Every user will have his own system account and can access one or more virtual environment.

One virtual environment should be considered per project.

Plus you can use ***pyenv*** to enable you working / switching with multiple python versions.

Also the only con here is that you will need an extra disk space.

Answer (score 0):

While docker is a possibility, it might be too much configuration overhead.

However, [conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) can possibly be a solution.
These allow for different (python) libraries to co-exists in isolated environments next to each other.
Easiest is to install Miniconda systemwide and let everyone create their own conda environments as theu desire.